# How to Fix 'SCRIPT_NAME' while run php script using php-cgi?

Tags: nginx, php, https, wordpress, php-cgi

I am trying to run below php file using Putty in wordpress.

```
php-cgi -f info.php
```

But this command throw this error  **Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME.**

Server Setting:

```
 #fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
 fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 include        fastcgi_params;
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Could it be that `SCRIPT_NAME` and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` aren't the same thing?

Comment: I think both are different. SCRIPT_NAME its file name and  SCRIPT_FILENAME is the full path of file

Comment: You missed the intent of my comment. The undefined index is for `SCRIPT_NAME`, while you pass `SCRIPT_FILENAME` to the params.

Comment: We are getting issue on wp-includes/load.php on line100. here is code: // Fix for Dreamhost and other PHP as CGI hosts
    if ( strpos( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'php.cgi' ) !== false )

Comment: I think you need: `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`

Comment: It is usually defined as `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;` inside the `fastcgi_params` file.

Comment: I just added but didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

There was an update to nginx or php (can't remember which broke it), but you need two entries in your `fastcgi_params`:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
```

At least, that's how -we- fixed it here. Give it a shot and let me know :)